# In Presto SQL how to create a map of array values and its count

Tags: sql, presto

If I have a table like below, how do I get the map of the count of unique values in the arrays in column2?

| ID | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | [a, a, b, c] |
| 2 | 12 | [a, a, a] |

I would like something like the below:

| ID | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | {a: 2, b: 1, c: 1} |
| 2 | 12 | {a: 3} |

I tried to use Presto's `[histogram][1]` for this. But it is an aggregate function that requires `group by`. I need to use the `histogram` for each row and not the entire table.

For example,

```
SELECT distinct ID,
       histogram(column1) AS column1,
       column2
FROM table
```

returns
`'"ID"' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) to expand your array into a column and then use `histogram` over this new column:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
             VALUES (1, 10, ARRAY['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']),
                    (2, 12, ARRAY['a', 'a', 'a'])
         ) AS t (ID, Column1, Column2))

SELECT
    ID, Column1, histogram(Col2) as Column2
FROM
    dataset
CROSS JOIN unnest(Column2) as t(Col2)
GROUP BY ID, Column1
```

Result:

| ID | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | {a=2, b=1, c=1} |
| 2 | 12 | {a=3} |